# Excel VBA Macro Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently having a problem compiling a Macro that I am trying to make. I am either trying to use a Named Range or the actual range on a different sheet and copy and paste that data into the current sheet. I want the data to post to the current sheet so I can run this Macro on every day of the month. Here is what I have compiled but for some reason I cannot use the ActiveSheet. Attached is my code.

```
Sub Macro1()

' Daily Route Sheet

    Sheets("2").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:H44").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ActiveSheet").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you mean to have `Sheets("Sheet1").Select` but best would be to do this without selecting anything.

Comment: No, I am trying to grab information from sheet 2 - I named it "2" so our inspectors can quickly click on it. So what I am trying to do is our contractors like to copy and paste but they do not use special paste so it ruins our named ranges. I hid the ranges and I am trying to write something that copies from lets say Day 2 and can be put into Day 23 for example. I would like to copy the data from a different day and post it in the current sheet they are working in

Comment: And you have a sheet with name "ActiveSheet", if you don't have only need erase the line `Sheets("ActiveSheet").Select`

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for avoiding `Select` in your macros.

Comment: what is the benefit of `activesheet.select` ?! if it is already active, why would you re-active it ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting, cutting and pasting, consider

```
Sub Macro1()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H44").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H44").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H44") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H44") makes sense to me but how do I get it on the current sheet im working on. that's my problem I run into

Comment: Then change `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H44").Value` to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H44").Value`. Don't omit the `.Value` like I originally did.

Comment: @hipster_pete - Just change the left part of the formula to refer to the sheet you're working on. If it's not "Sheet1", just change that to "mySheetName" or whatever...

Comment: I don't want to do that because I want to run a macro that can be run on any day without having to change the posting location - Id rather have it on the current active sheet.

Comment: @hipster_pete did you see my comment?

Comment: @hipster_pete, So just change the left most `Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `ActiveSheet`... no? Seems straightforward.

Comment: @MattCremeens I am now completely lost but I did see your comment. I keep getting an error

Comment: This is what I inputed

Comment: Sub Macro1()
    Worksheets("2").Range("A1:H44").Value = Worksheets("ActiveSheet").Range("A1:H44").Value
End Sub
 the error I get is saying it's not in range

Comment: No, use `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H44").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H44").Value`

Comment: @MattCremeens THAT WORKED YOU ARE MY HERO <3

Comment: Glad to hear. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Sheets("ActiveSheet").Select
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Select
```

However, I agree with Matt on the point that you should try to stay away from `.Select`

Comment: I agree with that too - I like the = part, I am getting stuck on the getting info onto the current sheet I am on

Answer (score 0):

`"ActiveSheet"` is a string.
`Activesheet` is a Worksheet Object.

`Activesheet.range("A1").value` is equivalent to `Sheets(Activesheet.name).value` or to `Sheets(Activesheet.index).value`.

That is because `Sheets` (or `Worksheets`, wich are the same) , can be referenced in braquets () trough either their names (being strings), or their Index (number, wich is the sheet's position in the Workbook).

`Worksheets`is a collection (by collection , i mean a kind of array) of your workbook's sheets.

`Activesheet` is a VBA easy way to access a sheet wich is already active, in the same way that `ActiveWorkbook' for workbooks, or`ActiveCell` for cells. They are all Objects , not Strings.

Answer (score -3):

Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H44").Value = Worksheets("2").Range("A1:H44").Value
End Sub

Kudos to Matt for the answer!

Comment: Please don't do that. Mark Matt's answer as accepted instead, by clicking the checkmark next to it.